# MySQL Error 1242 even with ANY

Tags: mysql, subquery

I started to use OpenGeoDB to find the zip code and the city name. My MySQL query reads like this:

```
SELECT      `d`.`text_val` AS `city`, (
    SELECT  `text_val`
    FROM    `geodb_textdata`
    WHERE   `loc_id` = ANY (
        SELECT  `loc_id`
        FROM    `geodb_textdata`
        WHERE   `text_val` LIKE '08%'
    )
        AND `text_type` = '500300000'
) AS `plz`, `c`.`lat`, `c`.`lon`
FROM        `geodb_textdata`    AS  `d`
LEFT JOIN   `geodb_coordinates` AS  `c` USING   (`loc_id`)
WHERE       `loc_id` = ANY (
    SELECT  `loc_id`
    FROM    `geodb_textdata`
    WHERE   `text_val` LIKE '08%'
)
    AND `text_type` = '500100000'
```

If I run this query with a full zip code or city name it works great, but with the code above, I get the error code

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

I was using Google and I found, that I should use ANY between the = and the subquery. Do you have any idea how I could fix my code? Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: +1 for teaching me what `ANY` is! First time to see it. :)

Comment: Have you tried using IN instead of ANY ?

Comment: I get the same error if I use IN. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that this subquery is returning more than 1 row:

```
(
SELECT  `text_val`
FROM    `geodb_textdata`
WHERE   `loc_id` = ANY (
    SELECT  `loc_id`
    FROM    `geodb_textdata`
    WHERE   `text_val` LIKE '08%'
)
    AND `text_type` = '500300000'
) AS `plz`
```

**Update:** Untested, but give this query a try.

```
SELECT      `d`.`text_val` AS `city`, `d2`.`text_val` AS `plz`, `c`.`lat`, `c`.`lon`
FROM        `geodb_textdata`    AS  `d`
LEFT JOIN  `geodb_textdata`    AS  `d2` USING (`loc_id`)
LEFT JOIN   `geodb_coordinates` AS  `c` USING   (`loc_id`)
WHERE       `d`.`text_val` LIKE '08%' AND `d`.`text_type` = '500100000'
AND         `d2`.`text_val` LIKE '08%' AND `d2`.`text_type` = '500300000'
```

Comment: Yes it does, because there are more zip codes that start with 08.

Comment: This is a problem. Why is it a subquery? Why not just add `text_val` and `WHERE text_val LIKE '08%'` to the main query?

Comment: That won't work, because OpenGeoDB stores the zip codes and the city names in the same column, called text_val. If I do that, I just get the zip code or the city name and I need both. :/ I guess I need to do two queries. :/

Comment: You could probably do it in one query with a self join. What does the data look like in the text_val column?

Comment: There are different values stored. Zip codes, city names, city codes etc. They get identified by the text_type value. 500100000 is the city name and 500300000 is the zip code.